# Redirecting to a photo with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I'm using htaccess
I have a hidden directory which I'd rather not be used and I want shorter links:

I would like

```
http://example.com/12940.png
```

to goto

```
http://example.com/_images/12940.png
```

Here's my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\/]+).([A-Za-z]+)$  "_images/$1.$2"
```

What's wrong with it, I get 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you have to do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.([a-z]+)$ _images/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

by using NC (case insensitive) you don't need to put A-Za-Z and L means the last rule in case you have other rules after this one.

Answer (score 0):

This rule fails because you have a `/` in it. So the redirected URL (`_images/12940.png`) is caught by the rule again, and mod_rewrite trys to redirect it to (`_images/_images/12940.png`).

So you should check if the path starts allready with `_images`:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!_images)([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\/]+).([A-Za-z]+)$  "_images/$1.$2"
```

Also you could further improve your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!_images)([a-z0-9_\-/]+\.[a-z]+)$  _images/$1 [NC]
```

No need to escape the `_` and `/`, but you should escape the `.` because it matches any character otherwise. The `NC` makes the rule caseinsensitive, so you don't need the extra `A-Z`.